# facebook graph api user access token procedure

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I created multiple apps within facebook to generate app access tokens which I use from multiple web applications to access the graph api.

I know that the user private data is not accessible unless they authorize the app to access their data.

I have a few users who are granting full access to their data and would like to convert the apps to get user access tokens and get the user feeds which include all posts. I have been using the access tokens with the apps not specifying any specific domain or localhost url and seem to be getting data just fine.

So I tried the following test: get one app to call the facebook login and enter my credentials which will give the app an access token to my user content. This fails to occur as when I enter my credentials it just shows the permission I am granting is my user profile info.

So if I wanted to collect an access token from one of these other users, then if they clicked on the url I send them would I get an access token from them to get their private data or do they need to create their own app and do the same and then provide me with the access token

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking - what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the language or the SDK version you are using on your apps. That could help solve your problem.

Anyway, I will try to provide an answer to what I think might be the quiz of your question:

> I tried the following test: get one app to call the facebook login and
>   enter my credentials which will give the app an access token to my
>   user content. This fails to occur as when I enter my credentials it
>   just shows the permission I am granting is my user profile info.

You need to provide the "scope" parameter on your login request, just like this:

```
FB.login(function(){
 FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello, world!'});
}, {scope: 'read_stream'});
```

on the Javascript SDK, or like this:

```
$helper->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'scope' => 'read_stream'
    )
);
```

on the PHP SDK.

An important thing to consider is that you must request approval for requesting this permission TO FACEBOOK for all your apps that require it (each one of them, separately), through the app's developer page. Unless facebook grants you this request, you cannot ask your app's users to give you this permission. You can go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/my-app-id/review-status/ and click on "submit a request" to ask for approval for requesting this extended permission.

Another thing you must be aware of: When you change the permissions required by your app on login, the user might have to delete the app from https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications and then log in again so the permissions dialog reappears.

More info on permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

If you are still stuck and your apps use the PHP SDK redirect login, you can also check [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/pull/54) I sumbitted to facebook containing a [basic functional example app](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/tree/f1916f3a1e8aeece518a18dc88f05775aadb9840/examples/login-logout-get-profile) you can tinker with to help you debug any problems you may be experiencing.